# Why isn't `date` respecting my locale?

Tags: date, locale

I am having some issues processing dates, where they are being interpreted in US format (mm-dd) instead of EU/AU format (dd-mm).  It looks like `date` isn't respecting my locale settings, or they are set incorrectly.

```
# This is correct, date read as US mm-dd-yy format
$ LC_TIME="en_US" date +%Y-%m-%d -d 1/2/03
2003-01-02

# This is incorrect, dates are read as US mm-dd-yy instead of AU dd-mm-yyyy
$ LC_TIME="en_AU" date +%Y-%m-%d -d 1/2/03
2003-01-02
```

The locale settings seem fine, as `date` can produce the correct format:

```
$ LC_TIME="en_US" date +%x -d 2003-02-01
02/01/2003
$ LC_TIME="en_AU" date +%x -d 2003-02-01
01/02/03
```

Is this a bug in `date`, or do you need to do something else to get it to respect the locale settings when reading short dates?

Answer (score 2):

GNU `date` `-d` option is expecting the provided date to be in "locale independent format", i.e. `POSIX` which essentially means US format as far as `xx/yy/zz` dates are concerned.

Comment: Shame.  Any way to get it to read dates in all the various fancy formats but in `dd/mm` arrangement instead, without resorting to regexes?  The dates I am trying to process vary somewhat and `date` can recognise them all, but gets the month and day the wrong way around (or reports them as invalid when the "month" is larger than 12).